# How do I award a bounty to an answer I don't understand?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have promised 250 rep bounties to five questions here. Recently I got 2 answers on [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18437/how-many-boxes-are-conductors) question from @DrXorile and @Hackiisan. However, I could not understand one of them, and am unsure of the other. Anyways, I don't want to rely entirely on my own math for such questions.

I put a 50 bounty, hoping that others would up/down vote the answers, so I would get to know which answers are, in fact, correct (and the award the remaining 200). However, this has not happened and there are only 1-2 upvotes on each answer.

**What should I do know?**

(a) I could just retract on the bounty offer of 250, and award the current 50 to the other previously verified answer. But this seems somewhat unfair.

(b) I could trust that the answers are right and award the bounty. But this has its own risks. Not only does it give my rep to a user for a potentially false answer, it also misdirects future users who will be more likely to believe in the possibly dubious answer and not bother posting or even searching for a true answer with a higher upper bound.

(c) I could ignore the current 50, and put a condition that I will award 250 rep when either answer receives $\geq5$ upvotes. But this also seems unfair, as it could possibly deny them from the bounty forever.

(d) Or you could come up with another better option. Please hurry, I have only *3 days left*.

Comment: If it helps, looking at Dr Xorile's answer, I believe that it is an effective solution.

Comment: Oops, I did not notice this discussion until now. Let me see if I can clarify my answer over the weekend. (Dr Xorile's answer is correct in my opinion as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to trust @DrXorile 's answer for 44 fuses (which I somewhat understand) and award the 250 rep. After this, I'm removing the bounty offer on the Q

I don't mean to justify my decision. And I'm not suggesting that anybody else do the same.

P.S. If you beat his answer within the week and get sufficient up-votes, you can get the bounty instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to the answerer(s) that they edit their answers to make them more understandable.

The answers look like they would likely be sufficient on [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com) or [Electrical Engineering.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), but the average Puzzling.SE user probably doesn't have the knowledge of electrical circuits and components required to understand these answers.

To be fair, the question implied a fair amount of electronics knowledge on your own part, which means the answerers might have assumed you would understand their answers without a detailed explanation.

All that being said, I think that **an answer that cannot be clearly understood is not a good answer**, regardless of its correctness, and therefore should not be awarded a bounty.  Give them a chance to improve their answers, and see where that gets you.

Comment: It's not that I lack electronics knowledge; it's simply that I couldn't understand the maths.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code, I'd appreciate if you could let me know where I should give a more detailed explanation (the 501-fuse solution? Or the 32-fuse one?)

Comment: @Hackiisan I didn't understand either of them, since some of the maths is too complicated for me. I don't know how you even got $I_j = \frac{V_0}{R(mk+A)+1}a_j$. I'm only a school student, so I don't know if you should even bother trying to simplify it. Maybe what you could do is add a diagram with the actual values for the $32$ fuses and resistors. I'll try some random values for $m$ and see if it works by manually calculating. If they do, I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: @Hackiisan DrXorile is also unable to understand your answer. However, if you want provide a circuit with the actual resistor values that works,you have only 5 days left.